# How to write relative file path for a file in java project folder

Tags: java, directory

The project name is 'producer'. I have a file located in project folder C:/Users/Documents/producer/krb5.conf.
If I want to write its relative path, should I write

```
File file = new File("krb5.conf");
```

or

```
File file = new File("producer/krb5.conf");
```

or

```
File file = new File("./krb5.conf");
```

?

Comment: That looks like a resource. If so: Better to load your files/images as resources:
https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans
https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse

Comment: Even though my answer below works, I completely agree with @g00se here.
If your `krb5.conf` file is a static resource, it belongs into the specific resources folder, which then requires some additional effort to load the file into the program.

Comment: Never concern yourself with your IDE - real software certainly doesn't. You can never tell from which directory real software is run, so if you DO need an actual file rather than a resource, use `user.home`. For one thing that's really the only place you can be assured of read/write permissions

Comment: if I want to address the file path as ${user.home}/producer/krb5.conf? @g00se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both your 1. and 3. option.

The 2. option would refer to `C:/Users/Documents/producer/producer/krb5.conf`.

For the purpose of testing you could try to get the absolute path from each file and print it.

```java
        // 1.
        File file1 = new File("krb5.conf");
        File file2 = new File("producer/krb5.conf");
        File file3 = new File("./krb5.conf");

        System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());
        // Output: C:\Users\Documents\producer\krb5.conf

        System.out.println(file2.getAbsolutePath());
        // Output: C:\Users\Documents\producer\producer\krb5.conf

        System.out.println(file3.getAbsolutePath());
        // Output: C:\Users\Documents\producer\.\krb5.conf
```

The 3. path may look a bit weird at first, but it also works.

`C:\Users\Documents\producer\.` points to the current directory, so it is essentially the same as `C:\Users\Documents\producer`.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question. I'm setting proj_dir value in environment variable. currently it is the project path 'C:\Users\Documents\producer'. However, I need to change it to a relative path too because I need to make sure it can run on any laptop not only mine.  I tried to set it to proj_dir: {'producer'} but it not works

Comment: What you're probably looking for is the `System.getenv(String)` method, which will return the value of any environment variable you specify. Your code for creating the file object would then be `new File(System.getenv("proj_dir") + "krb5.conf")`

Comment: Is that file meant to be written to?

Comment: the krb5.conf is the file app will read